# Rescue... Any suggestions?

Tags: java, minecraft, minecraft-forge

In General terms, the question is what to do?

```
 C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\AdoptOpenJDK\bin\java.exe -Dforge.logging.console.level=debug -Dforge.logging.markers=SCAN,REGISTRIES,REGISTRYDUMP "-javaagent:F:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.1.1\lib\idea_rt.jar=51431:F:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.1.1\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath F:\Games\forge\build\classes\java\main;F:\Games\forge\build\resources\main;C:\Users\...\.gradle\caches\forge_gradle\minecraft_user_repo\net\minecraftforge\forge\1.12.2-14.23.5.2854_mapped_snapshot_20171003-1.12\forge-1.12.2-14.23.5.2854_mapped_snapshot_20171003-1.12-recomp.jar;C:\Users\...\.gradle\caches\forge_gradle\minecraft_repo\versions\1.12.2\client-extra.jar;C:\Users\....\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.google.code.findbugs\jsr305\3.0.1\f7be08ec23c21485b9b5a1cf1654c2ec8c58168d\jsr305-3.0.1.jar;C:\Users\...\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\net.minecraftforge\mergetool\1.0.13\c18446ec4d5814f447d7a79b314ba9a27cc8dbc8\mergetool-1.0.13-forge.jar;C:\Users\...\.gradle\caches\forge_gradle\maven_downloader\de\oceanlabs\mcp\mcp_snapshot\20171003-1.12\mcp_snapshot-20171003-1.12.zip;C:\Users\...\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.ow2.asm\asm-debug-all\5.2\3354e11e2b34215f06dab629ab88e06aca477c19\asm-debug-all-5.2.jar;C:\Users\...\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\net.minecraft\launchwrapper\1.12\111e7bea9c968cdb3d06ef4632bf7ff0824d0f36\launchwrapper-1.12.jar;C:\Users\...\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jline\jline\3.5.1\51800e9d7a13608894a5a28eed0f5c7fa2f300fb\jline-3.5.1.jar;C:\Users\...\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.typesafe.akka\akka-actor_2.11\2.3.3\ed62e9fc709ca0f2ff1a3220daa8b70a2870078e\akka-actor_2.11-2.3.3.jar;C:\Users\Asus\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.typesafe\config\1.2.1\f771f71fdae3df231bcd54d5ca2d57f0bf93f467\config-1.2.1.jar;C:\Users\Asus\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.scala-lang\scala-actors-migration_2.11\1.1.0\dfa8bc42b181d5b9f1a5dd147f8ae308b893eb6f\scala-actors-migration_2.11-1.1.0.jar;C:\Users\Asus\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.scala-lang\scala-compiler\2.11.1\56ea2e6c025e0821f28d73ca271218b8dd04926a\scala-compiler-2.11.1.jar;C:\Users\Asus\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.scala-lang.plugins\scala-continuations-library_2.11\1.0.2_mc\e517c53a7e9acd6b1668c5a35eccbaa3bab9aac\scala-continuations-library_2.11-1.0.2_mc.jar;C:\Users\Asus\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.scala-lang.plugins\scala-continuations-plugin_2.11.1\1.0.2_mc\f361a3283452c57fa30c1ee69448995de23c60f7\scala-continuations-plugin_2.11.1-1.0.2_mc.jar;C:\Users\Asus\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.scala-lang\scala-reflect\2.11.1\6580347e61cc7f8e802941e7fde40fa83b8badeb\scala-reflect-2.11.1.jar;C:\Users\Asus\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.scala-lang\scala-library\2.11.1\e11da23da3eabab9f4777b9220e60d44c1aab6a\scala-library-2.11.1.jar;C:\Users\Asus\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.scala-lang\scala-parser-combinators_2.11\1.0.1\f05d7345bf5a58924f2837c6c1f4d73a938e1ff0\scala-parser-combinators_2.11-1.0.1.jar;C:\Users\Asus\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.scala-lang\scala-swing_2.11\1.0.1\b1cdd92bd47b1e1837139c1c53020e86bb9112ae\scala-swing_2.11-1.0.1.jar;C:\Users\Asus\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.scala-lang\scala-xml_2.11\1.0.2\7a80ec00aec122fba7cd4e0d4cdd87ff7e4cb6d0\scala-xml_2.11-1.0.2.jar;C:\Users\Asus\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\lzma\lzma\0.0.1\521616dc7487b42bef0e803bd2fa3faf668101d7\lzma-0.0.1.jar;C:\Users\Asus\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\java3d\vecmath\1.5.2\79846ba34cbd89e2422d74d53752f993dcc2ccaf\vecmath-1.5.2.jar;C:\Users\Asus\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\net.sf.trove4j\trove4j\3.0.3\42ccaf4761f0dfdfa805c9e340d99a755907e2dd\trove4j-3.0.3.jar;C:\Users\Asus\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.apache.maven\maven-artifact\3.5.3\7dc72b6d6d8a6dced3d294ed54c2cc3515ade9f4\maven-artifact-3.5.3.jar;C:\Users\Asus\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\net.sf.jopt-simple\jopt-simple\5.0.4\4fdac2fbe92dfad86aa6e9301736f6b4342a3f5c\jopt-simple-5.0.4.jar;C:\Users\Asus\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\net.minecraftforge\legacydev\0.2.3.1\f2cd4a8c9f09faf1c1e4a9a4c65df36e634f95db\legacydev-0.2.3.1-fatjar.jar;C:\Users\Asus\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.mojang\patchy\1.1\aef610b34a1be37fa851825f12372b78424d8903\patchy-1.1.jar;C:\Users\Asus\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\oshi-project\oshi-core\1.1\9ddf7b048a8d701be231c0f4f95fd986198fd2d8\oshi-core-1.1.jar;C:\Users\Asus\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\net.java.dev.jna\jna\4.4.0\cb208278274bf12ebdb56c61bd7407e6f774d65a\jna-4.4.0.jar;C:\Users\Asus\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\net.java.dev.jna\platform\3.4.0\e3f70017be8100d3d6923f50b3d2ee17714e9c13\platform-3.4.0.jar;C:\Users\Asus\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.ibm.icu\icu4j-core-mojang\51.2\63d216a9311cca6be337c1e458e587f99d382b84\icu4j-core-mojang-51.2.jar;C:\Users\Asus\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.paulscode\codecjorbis\20101023\c73b5636faf089d9f00e8732a829577de25237ee\codecjorbis-20101023.jar;C:\Users\Asus\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.paulscode\codecwav\20101023\12f031cfe88fef5c1dd36c563c0a3a69bd7261da\codecwav-20101023.jar;C:\Users\Asus\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.paulscode\libraryjavasound\20101123\5c5e304366f75f9eaa2e8cca546a1fb6109348b3\libraryjavasound-20101123.jar;C:\Users\Asus\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.paulscode\librarylwjglopenal\20100824\73e80d0794c39665aec3f62eee88ca91676674ef\librarylwjglopenal-20100824.jar;C:\Users\Asus\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.paulscode\soundsystem\20120107\419c05fe9be71f792b2d76cfc9b67f1ed0fec7f6\soundsystem-20120107.jar;C:\Users\Asus\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\io.netty\netty-all\4.1.9.Final\97860965d6a0a6b98e7f569f3f966727b8db75\netty-all-4.1.9.Final.jar;C:\Users\Asus\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.google.guava\guava\21.0\3a3d111be1be1b745edfa7d91678a12d7ed38709\guava-21.0.jar;C:\Users\Asus\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.apache.commons\commons-lang3\3.5\6c6c702c89bfff3cd9e80b04d668c5e190d588c6\commons-lang3-3.5.jar;C:\Users\Asus\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\commons-io\commons-io\2.5\2852e6e05fbb95076fc091f6d1780f1f8fe35e0f\commons-io-2.5.jar;C:\Users\Asus\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.apache.httpcomponents\httpclient\4.3.3\18f4247ff4572a074444572cee34647c43e7c9c7\httpclient-4.3.3.jar;C:\Users\Asus\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\commons-codec\commons-codec\1.10\4b95f4897fa13f2cd904aee711aeafc0c5295cd8\commons-codec-1.10.jar;C:\Users\Asus\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\net.java.jinput\jinput\2.0.5\39c7796b469a600f72380316f6b1f11db6c2c7c4\jinput-2.0.5.jar;C:\Users\Asus\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\net.java.jutils\jutils\1.0.0\e12fe1fda814bd348c1579329c86943d2cd3c6a6\jutils-1.0.0.jar;C:\Users\Asus\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.google.code.gson\gson\2.8.0\c4ba5371a29ac9b2ad6129b1d39ea38750043eff\gson-2.8.0.jar;C:\Users\Asus\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.mojang\authlib\1.5.25\9834cdf236c22e84b946bba989e2f94ef5897c3c\authlib-1.5.25.jar;C:\Users\Asus\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.mojang\realms\1.10.22\bd0dccebdf3744c75f1ca20063f16e8f7d5e663f\realms-1.10.22.jar;C:\Users\Asus\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.apache.commons\commons-compress\1.8.1\a698750c16740fd5b3871425f4cb3bbaa87f529d\commons-compress-1.8.1.jar;C:\Users\Asus\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\commons-logging\commons-logging\1.1.3\f6f66e966c70a83ffbdb6f17a0919eaf7c8aca7f\commons-logging-1.1.3.jar;C:\Users\Asus\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.apache.httpcomponents\httpcore\4.3.2\31fbbff1ddbf98f3aa7377c94d33b0447c646b6e\httpcore-4.3.2.jar;C:\Users\Asus\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\it.unimi.dsi\fastutil\7.1.0\9835253257524c1be7ab50c057aa2d418fb72082\fastutil-7.1.0.jar;C:\Users\Asus\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.apache.logging.log4j\log4j-core\2.8.1\4ac28ff2f1ddf05dae3043a190451e8c46b73c31\log4j-core-2.8.1.jar;C:\Users\Asus\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.apache.logging.log4j\log4j-api\2.8.1\e801d13612e22cad62a3f4f3fe7fdbe6334a8e72\log4j-api-2.8.1.jar;C:\Users\Asus\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.lwjgl.lwjgl\lwjgl\2.9.4-nightly-20150209\697517568c68e78ae0b4544145af031c81082dfe\lwjgl-2.9.4-nightly-20150209.jar;C:\Users\Asus\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.lwjgl.lwjgl\lwjgl_util\2.9.4-nightly-20150209\d51a7c040a721d13efdfbd34f8b257b2df882ad0\lwjgl_util-2.9.4-nightly-20150209.jar;C:\Users\Asus\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.lwjgl.lwjgl\lwjgl-platform\2.9.4-nightly-20150209\b04f3ee8f5e43fa3b162981b50bb72fe1acabb33\lwjgl-platform-2.9.4-nightly-20150209.jar;C:\Users\Asus\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.lwjgl.lwjgl\lwjgl-platform\2.9.4-nightly-20150209\b84d5102b9dbfabfeb5e43c7e2828d98a7fc80e0\lwjgl-platform-2.9.4-nightly-20150209-natives-windows.jar;C:\Users\Asus\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\net.java.jinput\jinput-platform\2.0.5\7ff832a6eb9ab6a767f1ade2b548092d0fa64795\jinput-platform-2.0.5-natives-linux.jar;C:\Users\Asus\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\net.java.jinput\jinput-platform\2.0.5\53f9c919f34d2ca9de8c51fc4e1e8282029a9232\jinput-platform-2.0.5-natives-osx.jar;C:\Users\Asus\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\net.java.jinput\jinput-platform\2.0.5\385ee093e01f587f30ee1c8a2ee7d408fd732e16\jinput-platform-2.0.5-natives-windows.jar;C:\Users\Asus\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.mojang\text2speech\1.10.3\48fd510879dff266c3815947de66e3d4809f8668\text2speech-1.10.3.jar;C:\Users\Asus\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.mojang\text2speech\1.10.3\84a4b856389cc4f485275b1f63497a95a857a443\text2speech-1.10.3-natives-windows.jar;C:\Users\Asus\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.ow2.asm\asm-util\6.2\a9690730f92cc79eeadc20e400ebb41eccce10b1\asm-util-6.2.jar;C:\Users\Asus\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.ow2.asm\asm-tree\6.2\61570e046111559f38d4e0e580c005f75988c0a6\asm-tree-6.2.jar;C:\Users\Asus\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.ow2.asm\asm\6.2\1b6c4ff09ce03f3052429139c2a68e295cae6604\asm-6.2.jar;C:\Users\Asus\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.scala-lang\scala-actors\2.11.0\8ccfb6541de179bb1c4d45cf414acee069b7f78b\scala-actors-2.11.0.jar;C:\Users\Asus\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.scala-lang.modules\scala-xml_2.11\1.0.2\820fbca7e524b530fdadc594c39d49a21ea0337e\scala-xml_2.11-1.0.2.jar;C:\Users\Asus\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.scala-lang.modules\scala-parser-combinators_2.11\1.0.1\f05d7345bf5a58924f2837c6c1f4d73a938e1ff0\scala-parser-combinators_2.11-1.0.1.jar;C:\Users\Asus\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.codehaus.plexus\plexus-utils\3.1.0\60eecb6f15abdb1c653ad80abaac6fe188b3feaa\plexus-utils-3.1.0.jar;C:\Users\Asus\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.ow2.asm\asm-analysis\6.2\c7d9a90d221cbb977848d2c777eb3aa7637e89df\asm-analysis-6.2.jar net.minecraftforge.legacydev.MainClient
[2020-05-27 17:47:41] [INFO   ] Natives: F:/Games/forge\build\natives 
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by net.minecraftforge.legacydev.MainClient (file:/C:/Users/Asus/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/net.minecraftforge/legacydev/0.2.3.1/f2cd4a8c9f09faf1c1e4a9a4c65df36e634f95db/legacydev-0.2.3.1-fatjar.jar) to method java.lang.ClassLoader.initializePath(java.lang.String)
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of net.minecraftforge.legacydev.MainClient
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
[2020-05-27 17:47:41] [INFO   ] Main Class: net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch 
[2020-05-27 17:47:41] [INFO   ] Srg2Mcp: F:/Games/forge\build\createSrgToMcp\output.srg 
[2020-05-27 17:47:41] [INFO   ] Extra: [] 
[2020-05-27 17:47:41] [INFO   ] Running with arguments: [--version, ${MC_VERSION}, --assetIndex, 1.12, --assetsDir, C:\Users\Asus\.gradle\caches\forge_gradle\assets, --accessToken, {REDACTED}, --userProperties, [], --tweakClass, net.minecraftforge.fml.common.launcher.FMLTweaker] 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at net.minecraftforge.legacydev.Main.start(Main.java:86)
    at net.minecraftforge.legacydev.MainClient.main(MainClient.java:29)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: class jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader cannot be cast to class java.net.URLClassLoader (jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader and java.net.URLClassLoader are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
    at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch.<init>(Launch.java:34)
    at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch.main(Launch.java:28)
    ... 6 more

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: What version of java are you using to run the command?

Comment: JDK 11.0.6 (Updated today)

Comment: See [Java 9, compatability issue with ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46694600/java-9-compatability-issue-with-classloader-getsystemclassloader). It looks like that launcher was not updated to work for Java 9 and higher, in other words, you'll need to use Java 8.

Comment: I have just 8 Java)

Comment: No you don't, the warnings and the classes in the stacktrace indicate you're running Java 9 or higher.

Answer (score 1):

Running the project with jdk8 should fix the issue. There has been some problems using minecraft launchwrapper with other versions of java.

Comment: Aha, if only, all by analogy) In General, well, to hell with this Minecraft and mods for it))