# Dynamically load jars using classloader in Java 17(migrating from Java 8 to Java 17)

Tags: java, java-8, classloader, java-17, dynamic-class-loaders

I have classsloading code which is working fine in Java 8(it's a bit old code). Now we are trying to migrate from Java 8 to Java 17. While migrating to Java 17, we got an error which loads JARs at runtime. The message of the exception is :

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: class jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader cannot be cast to class java.net.URLClassLoader (jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader and java.net.URLClassLoader are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
```

So I found from documentation that :

> New Class Loader Implementations JDK 9 and later releases maintain the
> hierarchy of class loaders that existed since the 1.2 release.
> However, the following changes have been made to implement the module
> system:
>
> The application class loader is no longer an instance of
> URLClassLoader but, rather, of an internal class. It is the default
> loader for classes in modules that are neither Java SE nor JDK
> modules.
>
> The extension class loader has been renamed; it is now the platform
> class loader. All classes in the Java SE Platform are guaranteed to be
> visible through the platform class loader.
>
> Just because a class is visible through the platform class loader does
> not mean the class is actually defined by the platform class loader.
> Some classes in the Java SE Platform are defined by the platform class
> loader while others are defined by the bootstrap class loader.
> Applications should not depend on which class loader defines which
> platform class.
>
> The changes that were implemented in JDK 9 may impact code that
> creates class loaders with null (that is, the bootstrap class loader)
> as the parent class loader and assumes that all platform classes are
> visible to the parent. Such code may need to be changed to use the
> platform class loader as the parent (see
> ClassLoader.getPlatformClassLoader).
>
> The platform class loader is not an instance of URLClassLoader, but,
> rather, of an internal class.
>
> The bootstrap class loader is still built-in to the Java Virtual
> Machine and represented by null in the ClassLoader API. It defines the
> classes in a handful of critical modules, such as java.base. As a
> result, it defines far fewer classes than in JDK 8, so applications
> that are deployed with -Xbootclasspath/a or that create class loaders
> with null as the parent may need to change as described previously.

Went through different articles like https://cgjennings.ca/articles/java-9-dynamic-jar-loading/, [Java 9, compatability issue with ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46694600/java-9-compatability-issue-with-classloader-getsystemclassloader) and other examples but couldn't find exact solution.

My existing code in Java 8 for loading JARs at runtime is :

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLClassLoader;
import com.immunesecurity.shared.lib.Log;
import com.immunesecurity.shared.lib.LogDetail;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.exception.ExceptionUtils;

public class ClasspathUtils {

    // Parameters
    private static final Class[] parameters = new Class[] { URL.class };

    /**
     * Adds the jars in the given directory to classpath
     * 
     * @param directory
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public static void addDirToClasspath(File directory) throws IOException {
        if (directory.exists()) {
            File[] files = directory.listFiles();
            for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                File file = files[i];
                addURL(file.toURI().toURL());
            }
        } else {
            Log.warn.log(new LogDetail().toBuilder().fileName(MethodHandles.lookup().lookupClass().getName())
                    .methodName(Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[1].getMethodName())
                    .lineNumber(Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[1].getLineNumber())
                    .threadName(Thread.currentThread().getName())
                    .message("The directory \"" + directory + "\" does not exist!").build().buildLog());
        }
    }

    /**
     * Add URL to CLASSPATH
     * 
     * @param u
     *            URL
     * @throws IOException
     *             IOException
     */
    public static void addURL(URL u) throws IOException {

        URLClassLoader sysLoader = (URLClassLoader) ClassLoader
                .getSystemClassLoader();
        URL urls[] = sysLoader.getURLs();
        for (int i = 0; i < urls.length; i++) {
            if (urls[i].toString().equalsIgnoreCase(u.toString())) {
                Log.info.log(new LogDetail().toBuilder().fileName(MethodHandles.lookup().lookupClass().getName())
                        .message("URL " + u + " is already in the CLASSPATH").build().buildLog());
                return;
            }
        }
        Class sysclass = URLClassLoader.class;
        try {
            Method method = sysclass.getDeclaredMethod("addURL", parameters);
            method.setAccessible(true);
            method.invoke(sysLoader, new Object[] { u });
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            throw new IOException(
                    "Error, could not add URL to system classloader");
        }
    }
}
```

We use `addDirToClasspath` method which calls method `addURL` from the given directory to load all the JARs.

I need suggestions on how to make it work on Java 17 or re-write the classloading logic to be compatible with Java 17.

Comment: That's not a stacktrace, it is just the exception and message. Please add the stacktrace. You should provide [complete error message](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359146/why-should-i-post-complete-errors-why-isnt-the-message-itself-enough). In which line/s of the code you are sharing is the error happening?

Comment: What's wrong with the solutions on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46694600/java-9-compatability-issue-with-classloader-getsystemclassloader? What didn't work for your use case in each case?

Comment: @aled, thanks for feedback `URLClassLoader sysLoader = (URLClassLoader) ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader();` exception occurs. And the stacktrace is generic.

Comment: You should read the *solutions* provided in aled’s link, not just the question.

Comment: @Holger, I read the solutions and tried to implement using @aled's link. It gave this exception message : `Unable to make protected void java.net.URLClassLoader.addURL(java.net.URL) accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.net" to unnamed module @17f052a3;`

Comment: Again, you have tried to use the code contained in the linked *question*, which has been said to be incompatible with Java 9 and beyond. That’s what the linked question was about. You should read the *answers* and by “read” I truly mean *read*, instead of mindlessly copying whatever code you find.